# How can I make use of promises more readable?

Tags: javascript, promise, refactoring

I have the following code. Is there a better way to write it. It feels like when conditions and promises and querying from multiple tables are involved, the code becomes harder to read. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
fetchUserById = function (id) {
    var user = {};

    return knex_instance('user_info')
      .where('id', id)
      .first()
      .then(function (data) {
        if (!data) {
          return null;
        } else {
          user.info = data;
          return knex_instance('user_table')
            .where('id', id)
            .first()
            .then(function (values) {
              user.values = values;
              return user;
            });
        }
      })
      .catch(errorHandler('fetchUserById', id));
  }
```

Comment: Code review questions are probably better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: this could probably be achieved with a single join query

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I'll post them there from now on

Answer (score 0):

Instead of increasing the indentation level with each request, you can return the request to the original promise chain and add a `then` there. Like this:

```
fetchUserById = function(id) {
  var user = {};

  return knex_instance('user_info').where('id', id).first()
    .then(function(data) {
      if (!data) 
        return null;
      user.info = data;
      return knex_instance('user_table').where('id', id).first();
    })
    .then(function(values) {
      if (!values) 
        return null;
      user.values = values;
      return user;
    });
    .catch(errorHandler('fetchUserById', id));
}
```

Problem with this approach, the `null` that can be returned by the first `then` must be passed through the second one (and the third, fourth, etc, if you had some). An alternate method would have been to use exceptions instead of returning null:

```
fetchUserById = function(id) {
  var user = {};

  return knex_instance('user_info').where('id', id).first()
    .then(function(data) {
      if (!data) 
        throw "NO_USER_INFO";
      user.info = data;
      return knex_instance('user_table').where('id', id).first();
    })
    .then(function(values) {
      user.values = values;
      return user;
    });
    .catch(function(err) {
      if (err==="NO_USER_INFO")
        return null;
      else
        return errorHandler('fetchUserById', id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to increase readability is to separate part of the code into its own function.

I don't know what this function does, so I'm just going to call it `doSomething`. If you replace that with something descriptive it's easier to read in two places: The function itself describes the code it contains, and the call to the function indicates what's happening at that step in the calling code.

```
function doSomething(data)
{
    if (!data) {
        return null;
      } else {
        user.info = data;
        return knex_instance('user_table')
          .where('id', id)
          .first()
          .then(function (values) {
            user.values = values;
            return user;
      }
}

fetchUserById = function (id) {
  var user = {};

  return knex_instance('user_info')
    .where('id', id)
    .first()
    .then(doSomething)
    .catch(errorHandler('fetchUserById', id));
}
```